# How does webpack resolve imports from node_modules?

Tags: webpack, node-modules

When I need a library from my `node_modules` folder I do something like this:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import $ from 'jquery;
```

How does webpack know what file(s) it really has to import? Guess there's some kind of strategy what files it's going to check?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Webpack loops over [resolvers](https://webpack.js.org/api/resolvers/) to find the file you requested. It goes over [resolve templates](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) to figure out the exact path.

If you try to import a module that doesn't exist you'll see the error trace outlining all the paths it tried to use to find the file but failed.

Resolvers are a powerful configuration tool that could help you develop better code. I really appreciate that resolvers allow me to drop relative paths and use more [developer-friendly ES6 imports](https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/es6-import-statement-without-relative-paths-e1511d794f18#.ownno0ndd).

I hope that helps.

Comment: One problem i've run into with this stuff is that I cannot resolve async chunks from node_modules e.g. if a common js template has a lazy loaded asset webpack can't seem to find it, would you have any ideas on that?

Comment: I'm currently importing a custom CKEditor 5 build, using path "@/lib/CKEditor5-Custom". This dir contains both a "src" and a "build" dir, which both contain .js files. How can I know which file the import statement has resolved? I do not explicitly configure webpack to go for any dir in particular.