# How do React import statements work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When programming using React, we usually start with the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

And then we get access to React functionality somehow. How does this actually work though? Where are the react and react-dom modules located, and how does the compiler know how to find them?

Comment: It is related to webpack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875592/how-does-webpack-resolve-imports-from-node-modules

Comment: It's part of the Babel JSX transpiling.  The React Babel plugin would convert the code but without the import the React classes wouldn't be found, which is why you need to add the imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great article on [understanding es6 modules.](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/)

> **Basics**
>
> In ES6 each module is defined in its own file. The functions or variables defined in a module are not visible outside unless you explicitly export them. This means that you can write code in your module and only export those values which should be accessed by other parts of your app.
>
> ES6 modules are declarative in nature. To export certain variables from a module you just use the keyword export. Similarly, to consume the exported variables in a different module you use import.

In your example, `React` and `ReactDOM` are added to your projects `/node_modules` folder when you install them via `npm` or `yarn`. Once they have been installed to your project, you can `import` them into your code and get access to their exported functions.